# Extract years, months and days from columns to create an excel formatted date column

Tags: vba, excel

I basically want to extract **the years, the months and the days** from the corresponding columns and use them to create an **excel formatted date column** with VBA.

With screenshots, it should at first look like this:
[Excel Spreadsheet with Year Column and Date Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDMd7.png).

Whereas, ultimately, **the year column should be removed with only the date column remaining** (leaving aside the description) and **containing the excel formatted dates**. [Excel Spreadsheet with Date Column only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9x8j.png)

Now, there might be an easier way to accomplish this task but the method I've undertaken is to:

1. Insert two new columns to the right of the **Date** column
2. Select the **Date** column and **move over the months** to the newly created column on the right by using the **Text to Columns function**
3. **Format the blank 2nd newly created column** to the Date category
4. **Insert the date function** into the cells of this blank column and autofill it to the cells below. More precisely, this date function is: =DATE(A2,MONTH(1&C2),B2)
5. **Copy this New Date Column and paste it back** as values only for later purposes of sorting.
6. **Delete** all other useless columns (year,month,day)

Though this is feasible with the excel interface, I'd like to accomplish this task with VBA and so I've already written quite a bit of code. Unfortunately, being a novice in VBA, I'm currently stuck at applying the formula at the final date column.

Before you take a look at my code, I'd also like to point out that I prompt the user to select the **Description column as a reference column** as it isn't always the case that the the year column is the first column or that the date column is the 2nd one. What is absolutely certain, however, is that to the left of the Description column, there is, respectively, the date and the year column.

Finally, if someone would also ameliorate my VBA code by solely allowing the formula to be **applied to the first and last rows containing years or dates** (same thing), I'd appreciate it.

I thank you all in advance.

Here below is my code

```
    Sub Macro1()

'Set variables
Dim DescRng As Range
Dim DayRng As Range
Dim MonthRng As Range
Dim YearRng As Range
Dim DateRng As Variant

'Obtain reference column with prompt
Set DescRng = Application.InputBox("Select Description Column", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)

'Create new columns from reference column
Columns(DescRng.Column).Insert Shift:=x1ToLeft
Columns(DescRng.Column).Insert Shift:=x1ToLeft

'Assign variables to columns
Set DateRng = DescRng.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-1)
Set MonthRng = DescRng.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-2)
Set DayRng = DescRng.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3)
Set YearRng = DescRng.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-4)

'Seperate the days from the months with TextToColumns
Columns(DayRng.Column).TextToColumns Destination:=DayRng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

'Format the DateRng column for later sorting use
Columns(DateRng.Column).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"

'Apply Formula to DateRng Column


'Copy Formula in DateRng and paste into the same column as values
Columns(DateRng.Column).Copy
Columns(DateRng.Column).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'Delete the other Columns (YearRng, MonthRng, DayRng)
YearRng.Delete
DayRng.Delete
MonthRng.Delete

End Sub
```

Edit: I'm grateful for the insight your answers have brought. You've made possible a simple task with a short code, unlike my unfinished one. Learned a lot from my first post. Thanks

Comment: Is `Col B` (in initial photo) formatted as text or date? You can check by formatting the cell to a number. If it remains the same, it is text. If it is a number, the date will be converted to its corresponding serial number.

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I want to go from picture 1 to picture 2 with VBA

Comment: Column B in initial photo is not formatted at all*. I'd assume that it is left as general.

Comment: @urdearboy nothing changes when i format the column as a number. the value stays the same: "day month". I don't wish to be disrespectful but I don't see the link between formatting the Date column in the initial photo and my VBA code

Comment: Forgot to tag you and i cant edit my initial comment. @mentallurg I wish to go from picture 1 to picture 2 with VBA. The problem now is that I don't know how to apply a formula to a column from a first row to a last one. The first row being the first one containing dates from the date column and the last row being the last row containing dates.

Comment: The fact that it doesn't change when formatted as a number tells us definitively that the value is a string and not a real date that has been formatted as *dd mmm*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a valid string date with the displayed values from columns A and B.

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
    for i=2 to .cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row
        .cells(i, 1) = datevalue(.cells(i, 2).text & ", " & .cells(i, 1).text)
        .cells(i, 1).numberformat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    next i
    .columns(2).entirecolumn.delete
    .cells(1, 1) = "date"
end with
```

Comment: Uptick for not splitting the string. I didn't think `DateValue` would register the value in B as is. Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: CDate is another option and better for non-EN-US regional differences.

Comment: @Jeeped I must say the code works very nicely. Unfortunately, it doesn't work if my Year and Date column were shifted to the right which is usually the case when i work with bank statements. Would it be possible to, as I asked, refer to the description column and use the offset functionality?

Comment: Sure. Sounds like IIf and isdate will do that.

Answer (score 1):

I took a different approach than @Jeeped so I figured i'd share since I took the time to practice with your question anyway. You will just need to format Col A with desired date format.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim DayMonth As Variant

ws.Columns("A:A").Insert: ws.Range("A1") = "Date"

For i = 2 To ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DayMonth = Split(ws.Range("C" & i), Chr(32))
    ws.Range("A" & i) = DateValue(DayMonth(0) & Chr(32) & Month(1 & DayMonth(0)) & Chr(32) & ws.Range("B" & i) & Chr(32))
Next i

ws.Columns("A:A").AutoFit
ws.Columns("B:C").Delete
```

Comment: as I've said to Jeeped, the code works amazingly. However, this is only true if my Year column is the 1st column and my Date column is the 2nd one. If it be possible, could it be offset from the column containing as its first cell "Description"? For example, referencing this Description column from the user with a prompt.

Comment: You can’t modify that yourself? Why is your data not consistent? Are you sure you don’t want to fix that at the source? Doing that here sounds like a work around

Comment: Your photo doesn’t help as description just says “Stackoverflow”. Update the photo with a usable example and make sure the data changes accordingly. Still sounds like a data organization issue to me that should be fixed at the source if possible

Comment: After reflecting on your comment, it makes total sense to correct it at the source (setting the year column as the first one and the date column as the 2nd) instead of modifying the VBA code. My original intentions were to make the code as dynamic and simple as possible but I now realize that it already is. Thanks for sharing.